# Does anyone know where I can find iPhone search bar style?

Tags: iphone, css, uisearchbar, jqtouch, searchbar

I'm developing a site with jQTouch, but it doesn't have style for a search bar. Has someone come across a library or css for the iPhone search bar like the image below?

[image]

Comment: I googled for it and found no Search bar styles, but you have a screenshot there of it, can you not make one from that with Photoshop and some css?

Comment: True - you have the screenshot - where's the problem to create css now?

Comment: I just didn't want to reinvent the wheels, especially when I could find better ones.

Comment: It seems that `<input type="search" />` in HTML5 already does the styling: http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/. Can anyone verify that? It doesn't seem to have the magnifying glass icon and the cancel icon when I tried it in iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile provides a search input that does exactly that:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/#docs/forms/forms-search.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a searchbar in the [iWebkit](http://iwebkit.net/) library, you can use that to creata your own.

Comment: It doesn't have the "x" at the right end when there is input.